# Python "Hangman" Code

Tags: python, arrays

I'm developing a simple text-based hangman game (a graphical interface may be included at a later date) and there is one issue I cannot overcome involving there being more than one of the same letter in the word you need to guess.

Below is what I'm currently using in my code to define the act of the user guessing what letter could be in the word (via the function guess()) as well as the code telling the user if their guess is correct or not, or if they've guessed that word already (function guessing()). [ignore the confusing function/array/variable names, I have a weird naming system and they're currently placeholders]

```
def guess():
    global letterGuess
    try:
        letterGuess = str(input("guess a letter: "))
        if len(letterGuess) > 1:
            print("only input one letter, please.")
            guess()
    except ValueError:
        print("you have inputted something other than a letter. please try again.")
        guess()
    letterGuess = letterGuess.lower()
    print("you guessed",letterGuess)


def guessing():
    global correctLetters
    global incorrectLetters
    global lives
    global letterGuess
    global word
    global guessyLetters
    print("")
    print("you have",lives,"lives and have",guessyLetters,"letters to guess.")
    print("correct letters guessed so far: ", correctLetters)
    print("incorrect letters guessed so far:", incorrectLetters)
    guess()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print("")
    if letterGuess in word:
        if letterGuess in correctLetters:
            print("you have already guessed this letter.")
        else:
            print("you have guessed a letter correctly!")
            correctLetters.append(letterGuess)
            guessyLetters -= 1
    else:
        if letterGuess in incorrectLetters:
            print("you have already guessed this letter.")
        else:
            print("you have guessed incorrectly.")
            incorrectLetters.append(letterGuess)
            lives -= 1
```

Say, for example, the word is "rabbit" where there are two b's.
the code will accept that "b" is in the word "rabbit" but will only accept one of the b's, now meaning that guessing b again is impossible as the program will return "you have already guessed this letter". This makes the game impossible to win as there will always be the remaining second "B" you need to guess.

alternatively, I tried to create a while loop of "while [letterGuess] in [word]" however that only means that, so long as the letter is in the word, then the amount of letters the user needs to guess will keep depleting until it gets to 0 (pretty much, the loop means that if the user guesses one correct answer then they automatically win)

I have tried scheming a possible way of countering this by putting the individual letters of the variable/word into an array, then using that to pick out the values in the array that match the users guess. I've also decided that adding an array of blank spaces "*" and printing that, showing any words that have been guessed correctly replacing the spaces.
e.g.:
word is: house. wordArray = ['h','o','u','s','e'] , spaces = ['*','*','*','*','*'] (number of spaces corresponds with number of values in wordArray, if a letter is guessed then the corresponding value in spaces is replaced with the letter)

I've tried to bullet point a simplified version of what I want to try and do here:

```
split variable into separate letters
put separate letters into array
create array with same number of values marked "_"
if guess is in wordarray:
replace spaces[x] with wordarray[x]
for ALL spaces where wordarray[x] = guess
```

Summary - if I need to guess the letters in word "rabbit" and I need to guess the letter B, then I want my code to accept this letter as a correct answer AND also mark both of the B's as guessed instead of one. I propose that this could be done using ~two arrays, however I am not sure how this would be written. Could anyone provide any methods of writing this out?

Comment: Splitting the tasks is a very good way of solving a problem. Good job then so far. Now, I think you better try each points of your bullet list separately before asking a straight answer on the internet. Additionally, you can use task driven development method to achieve it.

Comment: Just another hint: You can store the word you have to guess in form of a string and only display the `correctLetters` otherwise `_`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how to go with the test driven development method (TDD) I talk about in my comment. Just for the first point of your bullet list.

```
word_to_guess = 'rabbit'

# How to store the letter of the word to guess in an array?

# Think of a test
# assertTrue(strToArray(word_to_guess), ['r', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'i', 't'])

# Now create the function
def strToArray(my_str):
  my_array = [letter for letter in my_str]
  return my_array

# Now make sure it passes.
if strToArray(word_to_guess) == ['r', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'i', 't']:
  print('that work')

# Now try to think of all edges cases. e.g   
# Ah... but now, we have duplicated 'b' letter, does it exists another datastructure to avoid have duplicated letters?
# Ah yes, I remember my CS classes! python's sets!

# Think of a test...

# Create the function.
def strToSets(my_str):
  my_set = set(my_str)
  return my_set

# Make sure it work...
if strToSets(word_to_guess) == set(['r', 'a', 'b', 'i', 't']):
  print('that work')


# But what if the word_to_guess have non-alphanumeric letters or uppercase letters?
# so forth and so on...
```

FYI, it exists **way better** method to do testing in python. the example is just for you to have an idea, I personally use [Nosetests](http://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). 
But it is up to you to use the best tools accordingly to your needs. I recommand [Doctest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html) to start with (you are writing tests in your docstrings).

Hope it helped you in any way.

Comment: @Polybrow My pleasure :) happy programming!

Answer (score 0):

You can define a new function which takes letters guessed and the word you are trying find, then iterates over them. **Whenever letter is part of the word increment a counter value and then compare it to the length of your secret word**, if the isWordGuessed returns true it means they have guessed the word otherwise the word has not been guessed yet.

```
def isWordGuessed(secretWord, letterGuess):

# counter variable
guesses = 0

# go through each word in letterGuess 
for letter in letterGuess:

    # if the letter is in word increment guess by one
    if letter in word:
        guesses += 1
# compare guess counter with length of the word
if guesses == len(word):
    return True
else:
    return False
```